# Enable login button as soon as user fills both fields in Javascipt

Tags: javascript, validation, user-input

I need to enable the submit button as soon as all input fields has value enterred. I have two input fields type text and type password and a button which is disabled (I set its class as "disabled" than use CSS to change color etc..), I would like to remove that class whenever the above condition is met. I added 'change' and 'input' event listeners to all field like below:

```
const inputs = [...document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"], input[type="password"]')];
const continueBtn = document.querySelector('continuebtn');
const signinForm = document.querySelector('#sign-in-form');

inputs.forEach((input) => {

input.addEventListener('input', function(e){
if (input.value !== '') {
  continueBtn.classList.remove('disabled');
}else{
  continueBtn.classList.add('disabled');
   }
}
});
```

Tried with `e.target.value.trim() === ''` as well

I guess the above would be applied to all inputs and check if they're empty when the user is typing, but I'm not able to make it work: the button is being activated no matter what I do.

I would need some help in plain Javascript as this is what I'm currently learning. no jQuery. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `every()` method to check all the inputs, not just the one that the user is currently editing.

```js
const inputs = [...document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"], input[type="password"]')];
const continueBtn = document.querySelector('#continuebtn');
const signinForm = document.querySelector('#sign-in-form');

inputs.forEach((input) => {
  input.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
    if (inputs.every(input => input.value.trim())) {
      continueBtn.classList.remove('disabled');
    } else {
      continueBtn.classList.add('disabled');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#continuebtn.disabled {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
<input type="password">
<button id="continuebtn" class="disabled">Continue</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for your rapid answer. Tested your solution, but the console is throwing some typeerror: Uncaught TypeError: inputs.every is not a function

Comment: Are you sure you're using ellipsis to convert the list of input elements to an array like you show?

Comment: What do you see if you put `console.log(inputs);` before `inputs.every`

Comment: Found my mistake! Stupid me: I commented the line with ellipsis when I was doing trials and errors. Worked thank to you.